# por qué cmd no me detecta python?

Tags: django, python-3.7, vscode

buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente: llevo aproximadamente 1 mes haciendo un curso de django y tuve problemas con mi notebook. tuve que formatearlo con la opción de no eliminar mis archivos, tengo windows 10, y al finalizar el pc me desistalo muchos programas no se porque, entre esos python,volvi a instalar python, y ahora cuando quiero ejecutar el proyecto desde la terminal cmd, no me reconoce python, lo desinstale y volvi a instalar otra vez, puse el path correspondiente en las variables de entorno y me sigue saliendo el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me di cuenta que la ruta que me indica cmd donde deberia estar python esta mal, ya que python lo tengo instalado en C:-----\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

me sigue detectando un directorio llamado python37-32 que no existe, que probablemente era donde estaba instalado python antes de formatear el pc. y a pesar que modifique el path en las variables de entorno al path correcto me sigue mostrando ese error, tambien puse el path en visual studio code, pero el error sigue, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el comando python en cmd sin activar el entorno del proyecto, si detecta python y su version instalada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que puedo hacer? espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay dos PATH, uno a nivel de sistema y otro a nivel de usuario. Verifica que no se encuentre la ruta en el path a nivel de usuario. También puedes ejecutar desde un terminal: `SET` a ver si no aparece en alguna variable del listado.

Comment: verifique en los 2 PATH, y tenia la ruta actual, es decir la que tiene la carpeta python37, en ambos PATH, la borre de las variables de usuario, probe pero me sigue saliendo el mensaje de no python, pero me indica el cmd la ruta con la carpeta python37-32, que no existe.

Comment: Pon en tu terminal `ECHO %PATH%` y verifica que el PATH que te saca contiene solo las carpetas correctas. Si no es así, es que en alguna parte estás añadiendo al PATH la carpeta incorrecta.

Answer (score 1):

Sé que esta pregunta es muy antigua y que posiblemente el OP no vaya a leer nunca la respuesta, pero por si acaso, y visto que ninguno de los comentarios y respuestas previas ha caido en un detalle importante, voy a dejar aquí mi respuesta por si es de utilidad a alguien que tenga un problema similar.

El problema (en el que no habíamos reparado) es que el usuario está utilizando un **entorno virtual**, como puede observarse en el prompt.

Cuando creas un entorno virtual, básicamente lo que se crea es una carpeta donde poder instalar bibliotecas adicionales "locales" a ese entorno, sin que interfieran en las que tenga instaladas python a nivel de sistema. Conceptualmente es como tener toda una instalación de python "local" en esa carpeta, tanto intérprete, como pip, como librerías estándar y librerías adicionales que se instalen a partir de ese momento con `pip`.

Cuando "activas" el entorno virtual lo que ocurre es que se redefinen una serie de variables de entorno para indicar cuál es el ejecutable python a usar, cuál es la carpeta donde encontrar la librería estándar, y otras carpetas donde encontrar el resto de librerías.

No obstante, por motivos de eficiencia, la carpeta del entorno virtual no contiene una copia de toda la instalación de python, pues no tendría sentido duplicar cosas que ya están en el python del sistema. Así, por ejemplo, en sistemas linux virtualenv podrá usar enlaces simbólicos que apunten a los ficheros apropiados "de sistema" en vez de copiarlos de nuevo dentro del entorno. Y en Windows se puede hacer por ejemplo que el python que hay dentro del entorno virtual no sea más que un "atajo" hacia otro python instalado a nivel de sistema.

Al crear un entorno virtual con `virtualenv` se crea esa carpeta, y también se crea dentro de ella los scripts que permitirán "activar" ese entorno en el futuro. Dentro de esos scripts aparecen rutas a cuál era el Python que se usó para crear el entorno.

Si después desinstalas ese python (o renombras la carpeta en que se hallaba, o lo mueves a otra carpeta), el entorno virtual dejará de funcionar correctamente, pues estará "incompleto". Eso es lo que te ha ocurrido.

La solución es volver a crear el entorno virtual con el nuevo python.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el `SET` y reasignale a `python` la nueva direccion que debe tener en tu sistema operativo.

`SET python=c:\directorio\de\python.exe`